# Integral Domain and PID Proof

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing, integral-domain

Prove that, in a domain, $(a)=(b)$ iff $a = bu$ for some unit $u$.

By $(a)=(b)$, it also means that $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ so we can write them as $a=bu$ and $b=av$ for some $u, v \in R$ where $u$ and $v$ are units. In a domain you can cancel nonzero elements and units are nonzero elements so will I use substitution to get something like $a=(av)u$ and domains are cancellative so the $a$ terms will cancel and I will get $0=uv$ which suggests that either u or v must be $0$ but units can't be zero...

I just don't know where to take it from here or if I'm on the right track.

Comment: You can't cancel $a$ since you don't know that it is invertible. Instead write $a(1-vu)=0$. Since we are in a domain, either $a=0$ or $vu=1$. Since the case $a=0$ is trivial, we are left with $v$ and $u$ are units, which is what you wanted.

Comment: Ok- thanks. Do you have any hints or tips when showing that a=bu implies (a)=(b)?

Comment: Try reading the answers given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652960/suppose-r-is-an-integral-domain-prove-that-a-b-if-and-only-if-b-ua-wh?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for that link- I must have missed it!

Comment: I just answered that very question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693142/divisibility-and-principal-ideal-domain-proof/693164#693164